# How Swift Container of some Type, which owns all the same properties of this Type?

Tags: swift

I want to create a container of some generic type, looks like

```swift
struct AwesomeContainer<Element> {
    let object: Element
}
```

For example, define a `AwesomeContainer` with a `CGSize` Element.

I know that CGSize has `width` and `height` properties, maybe more.

How to make this AwesomeContainer automatically owns all the same properties which `CGSize` does, then I can get a new AwesomeContainer object via `width` property:

```swift
let awesomeSize = AwesomeContainer<CGSize>(object: .zero)

let awesomeWidth = awesomeSize.width // AwesomeContainer<CGFloat>
```

Is there any possible to make it?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily suggest it, but I think it's possible. See https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dynamic-member-lookup/

Comment: Although this looks like one of those situations where the key question is "then what?". If you could do this, what would you use it for?

Comment: @Alexander Wow! This dynamic-member-lookup feature is what i'm looking for! I'm doing some thing that using DSL writing UIView looks like SwiftUI, I need some thing like Binding<T> to automatically refresh my UI